# Form data is empty while posting form through ajax using jquery in WordPress

Tags: ajax

I am sending a form through ajax using jquery in `WordPress` but unfortunately i get form empty in `console`.

Here is my jquery code -

```
function step1SaveData(){
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#tpform1')[1]);
    console.log(formData);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://lexem.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        data:{
            action:'tpartners',
            formdata:formData,
        },
        success:function(data){
            var insertedID = data.trim();
            if(insertedID!='fail'){
            }else{
                console.log('fail');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

And here is my ajax file code -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tpartners', 'save_update_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_tpartners', 'save_update_data' );

function save_update_data(){

    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);

}
```

Ajax file returns 0.

So please help me to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GrayCarry now it says `site_url` is not defined.

Comment: site_url() is PHP, this is in the Javascript code if I'm reading the question right

Comment: We'll need to see your HTML to diagnose this, if your console.log is returning null then you've got a mistake in how you're grabbing the form data.  May I ask why you're using `FormData` instead of `.serialize()`?

Comment: @mrben522  Yes that is jquery code.

Comment: @mrben522 actually i have to post image also that's why i am using `FormData()` function.

Comment: show us your HTML

Comment: @mrben522,
Yes now i have data `(13) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]` in console but in php `POST` is still empty.

Comment: @mrben522 `HTML` is very big so is it okay to put it here? please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.serialize()` instead of `FormData`

```
 function step1SaveData(){
    var formData = jQuery('#tpform1').serialize();
    console.log(formData);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'http://lexem.in/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data:{
            action:'tpartners',
            formdata:formData,
        },
        success:function(data){
            var insertedID = data.trim();
            if(insertedID!='fail'){
            }else{
                console.log('fail');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

or use `.serializeArray()` if you want your data in an array instead of a string.

EDIT - from the comments, remove `processData:false` and `contentType:false` from the ajax call

Comment: I have used `.serialize()` function but unfortunately it does not post file data.

Comment: Okay i use `serializeArray()` function now and let's see what happens.... update you asap.

Comment: i have data in console now by using `serializeArray()` function but `POST` is still empty, unfortunately.

Comment: So, finally problem is resolved by following steps - 
1. Remove  `processData:false` from ajax request
2. Remove `contentType:false` from ajax request
3. Use `serializeArray()` function instead of `FormData()`.

`Thanks for your assistance.`
`Cheers`

Comment: @Vipin can you please edit this answer or post your own answer with your result? I did not understand how to replace formdata by serializeArray.

Comment: This does not post the files in the form.